# window.location.replace and passing variables in URL history entries?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I am using `window.location.replace` for various things on an app and passing variables in the URL (www.website.com/?clicked=2).

The problem is that it absolutely floods the history with new entries (at least in Chrome). Is there a way to just have 1 entry for the page? I thought `window.location.replace` was supposed to replace the entry or so I have read?

Are there any other methods out there? If you use the app legitimately for like a minute clicking things, it will take up a page of history.

Comment: Take a look at [`History.js`](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/). It lets you modify the URL without reloading the browser window.

Comment: @Blender thanks, but I downloaded and tested the demo it had, and it still produces multiple entries in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can do that. `window.location.replace` will simply change an URL and reload page. As it is a different URL - it will be added to navigation history. Suppose the only thing you can do here - download full page with ajax. Little strange usage of ajax, but it will solve your problem with multiple entries in history. With things like [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) you can control what is in browser history, but page will be loaded with ajax anyway.

Comment: I don't actually know ajax, though I know what it is used for, but I think I understand what you are saying. Basically mask the old page. I suppose there's no hope ahhh

Comment: well... ajax is nothing hard, in general. But at the same time you may find a lot of problems with it.  And in window.location there is nothing that can help you. By the way - I see no any problem with a lot of links in history.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have a problem with ajax, it's that the history.js demo in the .zip doesn't even work. I guess I'll just leave it as is and hope the user doesn't mind a page or so of entries.

Answer (score -2):

Location.replace( does not make a history entry.